# ERROR: Couldn't find file 'jquery-ujs' in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my `_header.html.erb` file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico'%>
```

My gemfile includes the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'paperclip'

group :assets do  # Gems used only for assets and not required in production environments by default.
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'thin'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'

end
```

My `bundle show` proves that `'jquery-rails'` is installed.  So looking at my `application.js` file shows that

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Are all present and accounted for.

I am getting - `ERROR: Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#landing`

in `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #6 raised:`

```
3: <head>
4:   <title>SampleApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:   <%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico'%>
9: </head>
```

In Googling this problem, I understand that `jquery-rails` serves up both jQuery and jquery-ujs and that line #6 should call `jquery-ujs` from within `application.js`

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it has something to do with the 'Thin' engine.  I removed it and the problem when away.  I don't have time to delve into why this is the issue, but if anyone else wants to comment on why Thin is causing the error, be my guest.

Comment: I don't even have 'Thin' on my Gemfile. Is there an lead to follow in here?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following lines :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

With my lines :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>
```

Hope that will fix your issue !

Comment: I know the "rails way" is to just go with the flow, but circumventing broken code by directly including an asset doesn't seem to be a great solution. I have the same issue and I was really hoping someone could help identify what is broken in Rails here, and not just hard-code an external library.

Comment: You are correct. Rather, just copy that js library file inside your app/assets/javscripts folder and then mark that javsacript file require . That will include the jquery.js library in your application.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to imply there is something wrong with pulling from the Google API - it is actually much faster for most users (as the massive number of web applications that use the Google jQuery API will probably mean the library is already cached in their browser). What I mean is that I assumed Rails "/= require jquery" and "/= require jquery_ujs" pulled the correct version of the libraries for the rails installation, and by hard-coding specific libraries you break that for future updates. On principal, the idea of hard-coding around framework problems bothers me on several levels.

Comment: Yes you are right. putting a fixed asset in your javascript folder / putting  the same version in application.html will not give you latest update. 
in that case, it's advisable to make things global by mentioning gem 'gem_name' in your Gemfile, which will ensure you get the latest build :)